# Как повернуть изображение на 90 градусов

Tags: java, android

Реализовал камеру для своего приложения, делаю снимок т.о:

```
public void savedPhoto(View v) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                String path = photoFile.getPath();

                intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PhotoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", path);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

где передаю путь изображения в другую `activity`. В `PhotoActivity` я ловлю путь полученного снимка:

```
 String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

 imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image);
 imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
```

После чего рисую его в `ImageView`. Все работает, но только изображение поворачивается на -90 градусов. Как повернуть `ImageView` или само изображение на 90 градусов, чтобы оно смотрелось нормально?

Comment: в идеале вам надо поворачивать картинку на основе exif информации

Comment: оно не всегда будет повернутым, как мне кажется.

Comment: Если делать снимок в горизонтальном режиме, то его отображение нормальное, а если в вертикальном, то он поворачивается на -90 гр.

Comment: Значит, вам надо получать из базы данных мультимедиа правильный угол

Comment: А можно пример?

Answer (score 4):

Получаем ориентацию:

```
ExifInterface exif = null;
try {
    exif = new ExifInterface(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                                       ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

Поворачиваем изображение соответственно ониентации:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            return bitmap;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
           matrix.setRotate(90);
           break;
       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
           matrix.setRotate(-90);
           matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
           break;
       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
           matrix.setRotate(-90);
           break;
       default:
           return bitmap;
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```